# SQL with an error

Tags: sql-server, sql

I am trying to create a table using SQL STUDIO and keep receiving this syntax error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'CourseNo'.

[image: screenshot of SQL Studio code]

[image: screenshot of error message after using INSERT INTO]

Comment: Looks like you've just stuck your data in there without telling SQL where you want it to go. You might need something like `INSERT INTO Course (CourseNo, CrsDesc, CrsUnits) ...` Take a look [here](https://www.quackit.com/sql_server/sql_server_2017/tutorial/insert_data_in_sql_server_2017.cfm) if it works, write it down as an answer to your question below.

Comment: I tried Insert into course previously and it began spitting out a different syntax error

Comment: Please don't remove information from your question, add it as new information.

Comment: This is my first time on this website did not know

Comment: Since you now get a different error, the `INSERT INTO Course (...) ...` command must be correct now. Take a careful look at the first example from the link I posted, compare it to your code and adjust accordingly.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT That's pretty much it, there's a bit more syntax/formatting involved though.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Yeah, he wasn't too far off, just needed a nudge.... good eye!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the creation of the table done correctly, but you aren't telling SQL what you want to do with the data you have after it.

To `INSERT` data into a table you need to use the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (Field1, Field2, Field3)
  VALUES ('Entry1', 'Entry2, 77);
```

You can either put each row into it's own `VALUES (...);` line as seen above; or separate them all by with a comma and insert them all as one block of values:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (Field1, Field2, Field3)
  VALUES ('Entry1', 'Entry2', 77),
         ('Entry3', 'Entry4', 134),
         ('Entry5', 'Entry6', 53),
         ('Entry7', 'Entry8', 743);
```

Answer (score 0):

The create table statement looks ok. The insert statement needs a values clause and each of the value rows should be enclosed by brackets, i.e.

```
insert into COURSE (CourseNo, CrsDesc, CrsUnits) values
('FIN300', 'Fundamentals of Finance', 4),
('FIN450', 'Principles of Investments', 4),
('FIN480', 'Corporate Finance, 4);
```

Each values row should have brackets enclosing it and a comma after it. The last one should have a semicolon.